# Use of 'or' ( || ) operator giving 'Cannot resolve flag' error in android studio (XML)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Using 'or' ( | ) operator in XML android studio is giving error, although the app is compiling correctly and working fine.

I needed to display contents of a `TextView` at its bottom right so I used ( | ) `or` operator to join them, but android studio is giving error.

```xml
        android:gravity="end | bottom | center_vertical"
```

The above line of code was giving 3 `Cannot resolve flag: 17` errors, which disappeared if I removed the `or` operators and used only any one of the `end/bottom/center_vertical`.
The thing to note is that even though android studio was giving the errors(not warning) but still the app as running without any issue.

I just want to know why it is giving error at the first place and is there any better way of doing the same?

Here's the full `TextView` code

```xml
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:gravity="end | bottom | center_vertical"
        android:maxLength="12"
        android:textSize="46sp"
        android:text=""/>
```

What I've already tried -

1. Using || instead of | gives the same errors
2. Restarting the IDE (found an answer which mentioned it may help remove accidental error markings, but not helping in my case).
3. Using the `Repair IDE` opton in Android Studio.

Comment: `android:gravity="bottom|end"` for bottom end. Why do you add unncecessary `center_vertical`?

Comment: @deadfish removing `center_vertical` is removing only one error. I know that `center_vertical` was unnecessary but I still kept it because only after adding second `or` I came to know that the `or` operator is causing the error. Is there any alternative to `or` operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the spaces to make it `end|bottom|center_vertical`.

Also, I suppose you want `end|bottom`, center_vertical doesn't make sense with these two.

Comment: Thanks, I never knew spaces could have been casing those errors. In C, I was told to have spaces before and after an operator. I guess I need to unlearn a few things now.